# What are the historical origins for the naming of the word 'function' in its mathematical context?

Tags: english, etymology, historical-linguistics, semantics, linguistic-typology

I tried to look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics) but couldn't see anything.

The reason why I was curious to ask is because this word just doesn't make any sense for what it does.

If we were to reinvent all the words that don't make sense, and they become normal in a given culture, communication would be far more efficient and clear.

I'm sure that the linguists has plenty of examples (which they've already given examples for) of the structure of words just not making any sense.

Comment: Please do not [cross-post](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/394514/24489) on multiple SE sites.

Comment: The meaning of a word lies in _what people use and understand it to mean_ and nowhere else (and that can change over time). Its etymology may be interesting, but tells you absolutely nothing reliable about its meaning. See etymological fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymological_fallacy)

Comment: so you're saying a word makes sense to one person so long as the user uses the word in that sense? like 'dlkfveje' can be used with the meaning of function and it would make sense? even though the structure of the letters do not make any sense? just like the structure of the letter in function do not make any sense @ColinFine

Comment: @ambw yes, it's exactly so. The more so in mathematics. And physics, for example. Are the quarks really "charming", "beautiful" and so on?

Comment: For example, the number pi has nothing to do with the Greek letter that is used as its name

Comment: sure that is semantics, and there's various key ways of 'meaning-making' but it doesn't make sense to me and others. -- is there a term for the structure of letters in a word? so i dont clutter up the site with a separate question. also a term about the structure making sense or not? extraordinary would be one of the few word that actually makes sense. giant would not make any sense, it's a random string of letters starting from 'g' for absolutely no reason, randomly from nothing. superbig would make sense. @ArtemijKeidan

Comment: @ambw how does superbig make sense, as I'm having trouble following you.  If you're going to break it down into super and big -- then aren't they the meaningless collocations of letters that you're complaining about?

Comment: @StoneyB I did some digging up of old MSE posts, and [**Shog9 ♦** says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16708/309993), "there's value in having similar questions posted to multiple sites, so long as they're actually on-topic for the sites they're posted to." Example [1](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/38478/30880) and [2](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/6095/97789)

Comment: @ambw: Words (which don't consist of letters  - letters are part of writing which is an optional extra which tells you almost nothing about language) are what they are. They come from all sorts of different places for all sorts of different reasons and - in most cases - nobody worked out what they should be, they just happened. So for some English words you understand how they're made up of parts: great. But many others are not (and the parts that the first group are made of are probably not, either, if you look at them carefullly). Sorry, but that's the way the world is.

Comment: 1 - words are made up of letters, even when they aren't written down. ideas is what you mean to say. the words represents the ideas. ideas come first, then anything that is used to represent the idea, such as words. 2 - yea the letters are always gonna be random, the only way to fix this is to redesign and reinvent, only after having understood the ideas that currently exist in a given society -- https://www.reddit.com/r/conlangs/comments/6lbm8z/light_overview_of_the_one_and_only_most_beautiful/ -- @ColinFine

Comment: @ambw: words are certainly not made up of letters. Written words are made up of letters, but many languages have never been written. Words are made up of sounds. They express ideas, but are not in general made up of them. I repeat: language is as it is, not as somebody wants it to be. Yes, I know about conlangs - I've been on _Word of Mouth_ on BBC Radio 4 talking about Lojban, which I had a hand in shaping. Historically, many conlangs were invented by people who believed that language could be "perfected"; but I don't think many people hold to that view now.

Answer (score 3):

Function derives from the Latin *fungi* meaning to perform or execute (source: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=function ), and from a mathematical perspective (disclaimer: I'm a mathematician) this makes perfect sense.  A function is something that performs an operation or sequence of operations to obtain a result from an input.  So I would disagree that that the word "just doesn't make any sense for what it does".

In English at least it's usually fairly easy to trace words back to their origins and understand how they obtained the meaning they did today as there are excellent reference sources for just that.  Learning how to use them well might be tricky though.  Reinventing all words that "don't make sense[1]" is probably more effort than just throwing them away though: you might want to look *Newspeak* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newspeak ) to see where that could lead.

[1] I disagree here as well I'm afraid: a word with a meaning, by definition, makes sense.

Comment: the structure of the letters for this and many words do not make any sense, why was it named 'function'? -- it was first used to designate a geometric object associated with a curve, im going to have to ask a semantics question because this clearly doesn't make any sense

Comment: @postmortes concerning your last statement on words with meanings: it's fine in maths, but does not work in the ordinarily language quite often. In many occasions we don't really get the exact meaning of some other's words. Then we ask them to reformulate and eventually reach an agreement on the intended meaning. But it's not as automatic as we would like it to be. The whole philosophy of language was not able to solve this issue.

Comment: yea language is highly highly limited and everyone in this lifetime should understand this basic thing about language by now, we're in 2017 already.. ppl didnt spent their entire life so we can learn nothing -- wittgenstein https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEPcQ6sIOTY

Comment: @ArtemijKeidan but a word with multiple meanings still makes sense, even if it requires disambiguation.  (For that matter a word with only one meaning can require disambiguation: take replying to a negative question in English, where saying either "Yes" or "No" almost always requires a follow-up disambiguation.)  I agree it's not as easy as mathematics where the disambiguation is deliberately excluded.

Comment: @ambw can you give an example of how languge is "highly highly limited" please?  As I can't think of anything that I can think of that can't be expressed by language, which would seem to be the opposite of your claim.

Comment: watch the video, go learn, it's endless, there's 1-infinity of examples, im interested in the solution which there are none currently, the best solution sofar is inventing a new language @postmortes